# Server won't connect to more than one client (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, chat

my server class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server
{
   private Socket socket;
   private ServerSocket server;
    // constructor with port
   public void start(int port){
       try {
           server = new ServerSocket(port);
           while(true){
               socket = server.accept();
                   new ConnectionHandler(socket).run();

           }
       }catch(IOException i){

       }
   }
}

class ConnectionHandler implements  Runnable{
    private Socket       socket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private DataInputStream in   = null;
    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket){
        this.socket=socket;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream inp = null;
        BufferedReader brinp = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
            System.out.println(server);
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            // reads message from client until "Over" is sent
            while (!line.equals("Over"))
            {
                try
                {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);

                }
                catch(IOException i)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            // close connection
            socket.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        server serverr = new server();
        serverr.start(4000);
    }
    }
```

Here's my client class.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client
{
    // initialize socket and input output streams
    private Socket socket        = null;
    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private DataOutputStream out     = null;

    // constructor to put ip address and port
    public Client(String address, int port)
    {
        // establish a connection
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            // takes input from terminal
            input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

            // sends output to the socket
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        // string to read message from input
        String line = "";

        // keep reading until "Over" is input
        while (!line.equals("Over"))
        {
            try
            {
                line = input.readLine();
                out.writeUTF(line);
            }
            catch(IOException i)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        // close the connection
        try
        {
            input.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 4000);
    }
}
```

Trying to develop pretty simple chat application works via terminal, but I think there are plenty of bugs I have in my code.
The server can handle one client, but when another client comes up it doesn't connect to other clients.
What am I have to do now?
I couldn't find out where my problem is, waiting your helps.
Note: I am completely new to socket programming concept.

Comment: I guess your intention is to handle each client in a separate thread. But you don't do that. You just call run(), instead of starting a thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: isn't "new ConnectionHandler(socket).run();" starts the new thread ?

Comment: No, it just runs the code. Use `new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start()`.

Comment: @ShooterLensAim please click on the link I posted. I posted it for a reason.

Comment: thank you so much masters ! "new Thread (new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start();" solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ConnectionHandler class is a thread class, and you must wrap its object to a `Thread` instance and then call `start()` instead of `run()`.

So in the Server class change

```
new ConnectionHandler(socket).run();
```

with

```
new Thread(ConnectionHandler(socket)).start();
```

Comment: new Thread (new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start(); solved the problem,thanks.